Mattuck's Theorem for abelian varieties for a non-locally compact field
Let $A$ be an abelian variety of dimension $d$ defined over a complete ultrametric field $K$ of dimension $0$. Let us put on $A(K)$ the topology induced by the one of $K$ (for example, following Proposition 3.1 of Conrad's Weil and Grothendieck approaches to adelic points). By the Theorem 7 of Mattuck's "Abelian varieties over $p$-adic ground fields", the topological abelian group $A(K)$ contains a subgroup $A_0$ homeomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_K^d$, where $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers of $K$.
My question is: is $A_0$ open under these hypotheses? If the answer is yes, what is the reason?
If $k$ is locally compact (e.g. if $k$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$) this is the case, since $A_0$ is of finite index.

My intuition is the following: we embed $A$ in a Jacobian variety $J$. The Theorem 6 of Mattuck gives a subgroup $J_0$ of $J$ isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_K^g$ (where $g$ is the genus of $J$) and we define $A_0:= J_0\cap A$. Following the proof of Theorem 6 we can show that $A_0$ is homeomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_K^d$. The only thing left is to show that $J_0$ is open in $J$. I don't understand why the last point should be true. If I am not mistaken, the proof of Theorem 6 defines $J_0$ as an open subgroup of a certain neighbourhood of a point of $J$, but it is unclear to me why this neighbourhood should be open.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

This is a general fact about commutative Lie groups over ultrametric fields, see, e.g., Corollary 4 of Chapter V, Section 7,  in Serre's  book "Lie algebras and Lie groups".

Thanks for the reference! Is it easy to see that $A(k)$ with the topology induced from $k$ is an analytic group whose tangent vectors form a commutative Lie Algebra, as in Corollary 4?

It follows from the fact that $A$ is an algebraic group over $K$ and the fact that any morphism of smooth varieties over $K$ induces an analytic function on the set of rational points together with its induced topology. This ultimately reduces to the fact that polynomials have this property.
